# creating a dictionary and assigning multiple values to each key using loops

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, seq

I have the following dictionary, created with a set of keys, and I wish to add multiple values to each respective key using a loop (or any other method)

Note: *This is not a duplicate of a similar question, as I wish to do it **without** using default dictionary or set default

**Code**

```
def main():
    #Create an empty dictionary
    dict={}

    #create a sequence of keys (USING TUPLES) that would be used to store teacher's details
    seq=('name','salary','subject')

    #create a dictionary from the sequence above
    dict=dict.fromkeys(seq)
    print(str(dict))
    #........as of yet the dictionary does not have values

    #Add values to the dictionary
    dict=dict.fromkeys(seq,10)
    print("New Dictionary with values:",dict)
    #........this obviously doesn't make sense, as a teacher's name is unlikely to be all 10!!

    #Add multiple values to the the dictionary....
    teacher_detail_values=('Mr Moose','25k','Philosophy')
    for i in range(len(dict)):
        for j in range(len(teacher_detail_values)):
            dict=dict.fromkeys(seq,teacher_detail_values(j))
    print("Final New Dictionary with values:",dict)


main()
```

The code I am trying to work with in order to arrive at the most elegant solution is:

```
for i in range(len(dict)):
            for j in range(len(teacher_detail_values)):
                dict=dict.fromkeys(seq,teacher_detail_values(j))
        print("Final New Dictionary with values:",dict)
```

Any solutions with explanations appreciated. Please note that I do not wish to introduce any modules (so no default dict or set_default) as this is for beginner teaching/learning purposes

**Expected output:**
Teaching/Learning aim: **Using nested for loops**

```
Final New Dictionary with values: {'name': Mr Moose, 'salary': 25K, 'subject': Philosophy}
```

Comment: What are you trying to demonstrate with it? Who exactly are you trying to teach, and why not start with existing materials rather than trying to muddle through your own?

Comment: Edited my question jonrsharpe to include expected output. Using existing materials, absolutely - but as it is being taught sequentially, the current aim is to master the use of nested loops. If this can be done, that is the answer/solution I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Your output isn't valid Python. It also doesn't have multiple values for each key. The question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys` does not add values to a dictionary.

Instead, it is a class method for constructing dictionaries.
This means that instead of assigning the dictionary constructed via `fromkeys`, you need to merge it into the existing dictionary. More in depth, `fromkeys` constructs a dictionary with multiple keys where each value is the same. This is not the best approach for what you are trying to achieve but I'll give code regardless.

This confusion may have arrived out of the fact that you named your own dictionary `dict`, the name that the builtin class `dict` also has. You should probably give your variables more telling names, such as `teacher`.

Also, you do not want to loop through each property and assign to it each value but instead you want to loop through all properties and assign a single value, the one paired to it.

```
teacher = {}
for i in range(len(seq)):
    prop_name = seq[i]
    prop_val  = teacher_detail_values[i]
    teacher.update(dict.fromkeys(prop_name, prop_val))
```

---

There is a much more pythonic way even without introducing more modules

```
teacher = dict(zip(seq, teacher_detail_values))
```

I'll break down how it works:

## zip

```
zip(seq1, seq2)
```

This merges two sequences into a single sequence by pairing one element from the first one with one element from second one, until the shorter one is depleted. For example;

```
zip((1, 2), (3, 4)) gives ((1, 3), (2, 4))
zip((1, 2, 5), (3, 4)) gives ((1, 3), (2, 4)) since the second is only 2 elements long
```

The constructor for dictionaries (`dict` denotes both the class name as well as working as a constructor for the class, this holds true (almost) all classes you will encounter in python) `dict` will behave in a special way when encountering a sequence of tuples with 2 elements, as the one produced by `zip`.

It will examine each tuple in the sequence and map the first element of the tuple to the second element. So
    dict(zip((1, 2), (3, 4))) is the same as {1: 3, 2: 4}

Comment: I explained `zip` and `dict` a little better, I hope it helps

Comment: It does - however I did get this error:     teacher = dict(zip(seq, teacher_detail_values))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: The code is here: https://repl.it/J3Ke/0  any guidance appreciated while I figure this out. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's because you still named your own object `dict` and the reason why you should not choose these generic name. Your own object overwrites the builtin reference `dict`. Here is a working version https://repl.it/J3Ke/1 . I just renamed the variable and every reference to it.

Comment: Thanks - but if you see this: https://repl.it/J3Ke/2 it still does it when I've renamed dict to mydict (or anything else)

Comment: You shouldn't rename the `dict(zip(...))` since there you actually want to refer to the builtin class `dict` (And it's constructor).

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You note that you do NOT want the use of default dictionary, but for learning purposes here is a solution, if and when learners come to it that would utilise default dictionary - considered pythonic and modern in terms of solving similar problems:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict = defaultdict(teacher_details)
>>> for i in a:
...   for j in range(int(i), int(i) + 2):
...     d[j].append(i)
```